# How to show CS GO stats graph

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have seen this graphical stats representation on a stream. I'd like to know the name of this feature and how to enable it.

[image]

Comment: I believe it's only available for spectators, as I see it often is CS:GO matches, that, or available when the full game is won.

Comment: It looks like he is playing and showing it ingame: https://youtu.be/1r7NV9dsG6o?t=24m26s

Comment: It's only available when dead, or spectator mode, I managed to get that confirmed from googling a bit. BUT to bring this menu up I have no idea what key. I can't find any source that indicates what key it is. Not even on the CS:GO wiki itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing  <kbd>Q</kbd>  while either dead, or in spectator mode will bring up the graph.

Comment: Can you show the command that is bound to **Q** in your config? In the default config its bound to _"lastinv"_

Comment: It's bound to "lastinv" as well. I'll get a screenshot of the hotkey ingame, in my next game.

Comment: Weird double bind. Lastinv is the command for the last used weapon, but it changes the graph menu, too. And you are right. I can use it only when dead or spec. Thanks!